# How to export a Field's Allowed Value List in a feature?

Tags: 7, entities, features

I've made a drop-down list type Field and have exported it as part of a Feature. However, whilst every other facet of the Field (Name, Help text, etc)  is successfully exported the actual Allowed Values is not.

Does anyone know how I would include this in my Feature?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out this is a bug(?) in Drupal 7.

The Dropdown list field's values are not saved in Features on a per-instance basis.

This can be fixed by using hook_field_widget_form_alter in the Feature's .module file, eg:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_field_widget_form_alter().
 */
function my_colors_field_widget_form_alter(&$element, &$form_state, $context) {

  if ($form_state['build_info']['form_id'] == 'my_colors_node_form' &&
    $context['field']['field_name'] == 'field_dropdown_text_single' &&
    $element['#entity_type'] == 'node') {
    $form_field_wrapper = entity_metadata_wrapper('node', $element['#entity']);
    $default_field = $form_field_wrapper->field_dropdown_text_single->value();
    $element['#default_value'] = !empty($default_field) ? $default_field : '';
    $element['#options'] = [
    'Red' => 'Red',
    'Blue' => 'Blue',
    'Green' => 'Green',
    ];
  }

}
```

...drupal is so great...